# error while fetching pop3 mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I got the following error while fetching mail via pop3:

(the first 4 row are a prints of the email content)

```
15/06/2015 16:56:42   RunJava JVM: dcwTXKwiJYV2+XMArhAA+CmQT7elRfEfVfGumfETQdM0jX0eDUZTLDaTQBIowOCrsvzSLwT1HtWb
15/06/2015 16:56:42   RunJava JVM: 4o8SaM3x48NXI1SzNra2T2884mUpHKVnGxj0Byyj8an+Kus6OnxV8GGbULMLYu/2ovMFFuSQV3n+
15/06/2015 16:56:42   RunJava JVM: E98HHbOAc0ATa5e+MfAPjTw0174km1nT9buRbXEEkSxIjkhfkHO0DeGGMfdwTzXafEzxHrcniLRP
15/06/2015 16:56:42   RunJava JVM: BHhu4+xahqQNxcX5j3fZ4FJyVHQk7H646AfxZHEfHjVtMbxB4GK6jaHydRSaXEy/u4y0ZDtzwpHO
15/06/2015 16:56:57   CMPop3: Pec Segreteria - Impossibile inviare messaggio all'host SMTP 172.25.1.7: error fetching POP3 content
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM: javax.mail.MessagingException: error fetching POP3 content;
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:   nested exception is:
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getContentStream(POP3Message.java:199)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1701)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1659)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:215)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at CiemmePECThread.runNotes(CMPecThread.java:659)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM: Caused by: 
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:205)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.b.b(b.java:245)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:128)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:510)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:210)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.ibm.jsse2.f.read(f.java:10)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:248)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:77)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.multilineCommand(Protocol.java:379)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.retr(Protocol.java:263)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getContentStream(POP3Message.java:133)
15/06/2015 16:56:57   RunJava JVM:  ... 5 more
```

the error appear every time with the same email (the third email fetched).. emails are maximum of 610kb.. timeout is set to 15000

Do you have any idea about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change or remove the timeout, does it change the behavior?

Possibly there's something about that message that is causing the server to fail.

Comment: I've tried using 60000 as timeout and now it is working fine... thanks! (I can't remove timeout because some time it hang my server and with non defined timeout I need to restart it!)